# ORA-31626: job does not exist during schema export

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-11g-r2, restore, dump

I'm exporting schema with following command -

```
expdp system/system@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/orcl schemas=schema-name directory=test_dir dumpfile=Schema.dmp logfile=SchemaLog.log
```

but it results into following error -

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-04063: package body "SYS.DBMS_INTERNAL_LOGSTDBY" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_INTERNAL_LOGSTDBY"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1009
ORA-04063: package body "SYS.DBMS_LOGREP_UTIL" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_LOGREP_UTIL"
```

I googled a lot and tried solutions provided around `ORA-31626: job does not exist` and `ORA-04063: package body "SYS.DBMS_INTERNAL_LOGSTDBY" has errors` but none helped to solve the problem.

Could you please help to resolve this?

Comment: ORA-31626 ORA-4063 Package Body DBMS_INTERNAL_LOGSTDBY Has Errors During DataPump Export (EXPDP) (Doc ID 799625.1)

Comment: @BalazsPapp, thanks for pointing to it but that requires account with company details which I don't have and my company don't allow to do that. Could you please share cause, solution section from there.

Comment: Are you the DBA for that database?

Comment: No @GerardH.Pille, I'm not DBA

Comment: I don't know if expdp is meant to be used by non-dba's.  You would at least need the DBA to finish the installation of your database, some packages seem to be missing.  Can't you export most of your schema using exp ?

Answer (score 0):

Try exp in stead of expdp

```
exp system/system@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/orcl owner=schema-name file=/test_dir/Schema.dmp log=SchemaLog.log
```